# Blank window when editing list item

Tags: list, datasheet

I have a problem when I want to edit a list item.
When click on it or "..." edit item I receive white window with "x" all items of the list.

However when I want to add an item there is no issue; form is opened and can be filled.

Have you already seen this kind of issue? Thank you for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is is because of new List experience in SharePoint 2013.
Go to the list/library settings

Navigate to List Experience at the bottom and select Classic experience option.

Refresh the list and try to edit. This will resolve the blank page issue.

Comment: I do not see List Experience option in sessings of my list, even in advanced settings.

Comment: It is present under settings -> Advanced settings -> List experience